# How to Change pagination in SharePoint default search

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-rest-api

How to Edit or change Pagination in sharepoint default search page?
I want to put button for next and previous it is possible.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[How to add Previous/Next buttons to SharePoint blogs posts?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/175595/how-to-add-previous-next-buttons-to-sharepoint-blogs-posts)

http://www.sharepointempower.com/Blog/Post/15/Paging-using-SharePoint-2013-REST-API

Both links will helps you to create paging Next/Previous buttons in page.

Comment: Is it used in search page in SharePoint?